# Is there a way to run a Python script that is stored in a GitHub repository from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, git, github, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new to using GitHub to store my project and have just started moving my projects over.

Is there a way to run my Python file stored in my GitHub, but from Visual Studio Code? I already know how to open my repository in Visual Studio Code, but I don't know how to run it.

Comment: `git` is just your remote storage.  All of your files are still on your local computer, and can be run like any other script.

Comment: How are you opening your repo in vscode? That may determine how you go about running code in the repo.

Comment: @TimRoberts If all my files are still on my local computer, then where are they? I can't seem to find them. Please help. Edit: I just realized that I wrote git in the title. I'm sorry about that I meant github. If your comment still applies though, then reply as such.

Comment: Did you use git to put them on Github? If so, they are were they were before that. If you used the web browser to put them there, then they are were you added them from.

Comment: You either started local and pushed to GitHub, or you started elsewhere, in which case you need to `git clone` to get a local copy.  Since you mentioned VSCode, I assumed you were already editing the project.

Comment: @TimRoberts I actually installed an extension within vscode that allows me to open the repo without cloning it. The extension I used is GitHub Repositories v0.18.0 by GitHub.

Comment: @Wayne I used the website but my problem isn't that I can't open the repo. I can using the extension mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: You may have to go ask the folks who wrote the extension.  That's not a normal way of doing things, and life on the cutting edge is not always happy.  ;)

Comment: The extension description at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.remotehub says "quickly browse, search, edit, and commit to any remote GitHub repository directly from within Visual Studio Code. " So you are just using that to see the remote and commit. It seems you keep running your code local in VSCode the same way.

Comment: @Wayne Whenever I try to run my code, the option to run it doesn't appear. I've tried every way to run I can think of. The option just doesn't appear.

Comment: using that extension you have a remote workspace, VSC works as an interface to the file storage in a git repo on github, It is not a remote connection to a server where you have a copy running of VSC and your local VSC is just an intelligent terminal. Then the code runs on the server, github has no possibility of running/debugging your python code, make a local copy of the repo and open this as your VSC workspace

Comment: @rioV8 Ok I will do that instead thank you